# what is the function of "ip link" command?

Tags: linux

I've installed putty, and I'm trying to write

```
ip link
```

For what is it used??

Comment: to show information for all interfaces

Comment: Read `man ip ip-link`.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ip.8.html), it tells the `ip` program to manipulate the *network device* (rather than IP-address, routing-table entry or other "object").

For instance, showing details on my network devices:

```
$ ip -d link
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 16436 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DEFAULT qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:0c:29:48:c5:25 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

gives a different report than the address:

```
$ ip -d address
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 16436 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:0c:29:48:c5:25 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.170/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global eth0
    inet6 fd00::20c:29ff:fe48:c525/64 scope global dynamic 
       valid_lft 3570sec preferred_lft 570sec
    inet6 fe80::20c:29ff:fe48:c525/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

The details of course will differ across systems.

Answer (score 0):

- `ip link` list all network interfaces.
- `ip addr` list all network interfaces *and the associated IP addresses*